# How to convert string value to HTMLAnchor in c#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have 100  tags in my web page each tag represents an real world desktop. I have live status of each system in my database (online/offline data). If system is online i want add an CSS class to

```css
.online{  
  color: #fff;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    border-color: #4cae4c;
}
```

tag.

I already defined the id value of  to appropriate system name of particular system.

```html
<a id="comzk12"></a>
```

now i want add online class to particular  tag using c#.

```
string id=dataRow["comName"].ToString();;//I'm getting the system name from DB
    if(status=="online")
    {
        id.Attributes.Add("class","online");//id value is comzk12.
    }
```

But i can't use above code because this line

```js
id.Attributes.Add("class","online");
```

id is string. id of  tag is HTMLAnchor. I can't convert string to HTMLAnchor.

how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LinkButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) / [HtmlAnchor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor(v=vs.110).aspx) with the id you are getting from database, you can use `CssClass` too instead of adding attribute for class.

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
lb.ID = dataRow["comName"].ToString();;  
if(status=="online")
{
    lb.Attributes.Add("class","online");//id value is comzk12.
}
```

Comment: Explain what is not working, did you add the LinkButton to some container like Panel

Comment: Yes I added a LinkButton in div tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anchor node programmatically like so:

```
HtmlAnchor anchor = new HtmlAnchor();        
anchor.InnerHtml = id;
anchor.Attributes.Add("class","online");
```

Another way is to pass your 'status' information to client side.

It is possible since you can already print `<a id="comzk12"></a>`.

So, try to print `<a id="comzk12-online"></a>` instead.

Then, using jQuery:

```
$('a').each(function(i,val){
    if ($(val).attr('id').indexOf("online") >= 0){
        $(val).addClass('online');
        $(val).attr('id', $(val).attr('id').replace('-online',''));
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, you need to add the created HtmlAnchor instance 'anchor' to a parent/container and pass back to client side?

Comment: Another way is to somehow pass your 'status' data to client side. It is possible since you can already print '<a id="comzk12"></a>' . So, try to print '<a id="comzk12" data-status="online"></a>' instead. Then, using jQuery, $('a').each(function(i,val){if($(this).attr('data-status')=='online')$(this).addClass('online');});

Comment: i updated my answer for a possible client side solution. please mark as answer/upvote if that helped you!

Comment: Hi alexan thanks for reply. But I have issue to send that status data to particular <a> tag. That's the major problem.

Comment: that's why if passing as separate attribute (either as class or html5 data- tag) is an issue in your circumstances, how about you append "-online", "-offline" as string behind your 'id'? so you can print: <a id="comzk12-online"></a> and handle the rest using the jQuery code I posted above?

Comment: The query you mentioned is really helpful.but I'm going to create html elements programmatically.. That'll be little easier I suppose.